# Using angularjs how can I get checked and unchecked values

Tags: angularjs

Here I am binding values to ng-click as

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="a.CheckAssign"ng-click="myFunctionnew(a.ENQUIRY_CODE,a.CheckAssign)" />
enquiryArr=[]
$scope.myFunctionnew = function(enqcode,checkassign)
{
enquiryArr.push(enqcode + '&' + checkassign)
var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(enquiryArr, function (i, el) {
    if ($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) {
        uniqueNames.push(el);
        console.log(uniqueNames)
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(uniqueNames);
    }
}
```

Here when I check and uncheck the checkbox the value is storing multiple
Please help me how can I store Enquiry code and T/F values.

Comment: Can you please provide your output and data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you're running into duplicate entries in your `enquiryArr`.  You're running into this because you're trying to manually keep track of the array in an odd fashion.  While there are ways to correct the way you're storing it, it's even easier to have angular track what is checked and what is not.

Using the following DataSet:

```
$scope.enquiries = [
  {ENQUIRY_CODE: 'ENQUIRY_1', ENQUIRY_NAME: 'First Enquiry', selected: false},
  {ENQUIRY_CODE: 'ENQUIRY_2', ENQUIRY_NAME: 'Second Enquiry', selected: false},
  {ENQUIRY_CODE: 'ENQUIRY_3', ENQUIRY_NAME: 'Third Enquiry', selected: false},
  {ENQUIRY_CODE: 'ENQUIRY_4', ENQUIRY_NAME: 'Fourth Enquiry', selected: false}
];
```

And binding the `selected` field to your checkboxes `ng-model`

```
<div ng-repeat="e in enquiries">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="e.selected" />
  {{e.ENQUIRY_NAME}}
</div>
```

You can determine which one is checked simply by looking at the `$scope.enquiries` array and looking for `selected: true` (or `false` if you want to know the ones not checked).

In javascript you can use a simple Array Filter to get the selected values as such:

```
$scope.enquiries.filter(e => e.selected);
```

Or if you want to get them in your template, you can also use the `filter` pipe as such:

```
{{(enquiries | filter:{selected:true})}}
```

Here is an [interactive plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/HcdfcJ02GRNUbn4n?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1&preview) that you can view this.

*Misc Note: If you do want to run something when the checkbox is clicked, you can still use an `ng-click` and run your custom code, however, I would recommend using `ng-change` as there are other ways to change the selected value of a checkbox other than clicking.*

Comment: Thank u soo much for your Efforts

Answer (score 0):

I have test your code and its working fine. your problem is not so much clear so you can check following test code.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<div ng-repeat="dt in data">
 <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="CheckAssign" ng-click="myFunctionnew(dt.name,dt.volume)" />
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.myFunctionnew = function(enqcode,checkassign)
{
enquiryArr.push(enqcode + '&' + checkassign)
var uniqueNames = [];
for(i=0; i <enquiryArr.length; i++) {
    if ($.inArray(enquiryArr[i], uniqueNames) == -1) {
        uniqueNames.push(enquiryArr[i]);
        console.log(uniqueNames)
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(uniqueNames);
    }
}
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/light4star/2wj7gb0n/)